# Disabling Maps app in phone when shown in android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-maps

Right now I am working to show directions to a particular place using Maps app in Android wear. Following is my code.

```
String format = "geo:0,0?q=" + dLatitude + "," + dLongitude + "( Location)";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(format);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This works perfectly fine. The only issue is when I show the map in Android wear Maps app, it also opens up phone's maps app with the same instructions. May be its because the wear is synched with phone through Bluetooth. But The requirement is when I show the directions in watch, I should not open the phone's maps app. How can I control this programmatically? Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it's out of your control. It's the Maps app opening its phone counterpart, and I doubt there's an API to affect that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use intents to open the Maps app directly on the watch instead of just opening a Uri.

Comment: Can you add an example pls